# What add_rewrite_tag()'s RegEx matches against?

Tags: rewrite-rules, regex, rewrite-tag

I'm trying to figure out wether I can specify the position of the string to match (i.e. immediately after the domain) to reduce the chances of matching something else, but I don't even know what the RegEx in add_rewrite_tag() matches against.

Does it match against a full url including domain?
or
Does it match against everything after the domain?

Thanks.